# Ask about AngularJS ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs

I want edit page in most of the times. At that time, some pages wants to display that button can be disable and also some pages wants to display with enable. I want to use the same edit page. In here, I put the button. If you know, please let me know.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <center>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Remove" ng-show="IsShow" ng-disabled="true">
            </center>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the condition where you you want/dont want to disable the button

Comment: That edit page is displayed with disable condition in most of the times. When I click the verify page, it also displays the same edit page with enable button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a $scope value with ng-disabled. Please find the code below:

In the controller, you will have to equate the variable to true or false based on the condition.

```js
if(//someCondition) {
  $scope.condition = true;
} else if(//someOtherCondition) {
    $scope.condition = true/ false;
} else {
    $scope.condition = false;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <center>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Remove" ng-show="IsShow" ng-disabled="condition">
            </center>
</div>
```

Comment: In here, I want to get the same page with the different type of buttons (enable, disable). So how can i put the condition?

Comment: For example, in the a.html wants to display with enable button.otherwise the button wants to be disable.

Comment: Referring to one of your earlier comments: When I click the verify page, it also displays the same edit page with enable button. Call a function on the click of verify button and set the condition = true. I assume you are using the same variable across controllers (not a good practice). You might have to use $rootScope.condition = true/ false.

Answer (score 1):

A simple suggestion for you:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <center>
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Remove" ng-show="IsShow" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
    </center>
</div>

<button ng-click="editSomething()" type="button">Edit</button>
```

Controller:

```
...
$scope.isDisabled = false;
...

$scope.editSomething = function () {
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever condition it is, use it in the `ng-disabled` attribute:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="CONDITION" value="Remove" ng-show="IsShow">
```

Eg: if its a bool which is available with your controller `$scope.isBtnDisabled = false;`, then use it in the view as:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="isBtnDisabled" value="Remove" ng-show="IsShow">
```